# sharethis and jquery help

Tags: javascript, social-media, sharethis, jquery

I have some HTML that looks like this,

```
<div class="suit-gallery">
  <img src="../images/galleries/business/DSC_0035_sm.jpg" alt="Stylish button 2 business suit with contrast buttonholes light weight high twist cool wool" width="164" height="247" />
  <div class="suit-gallery-btn">
    <a href="../images/galleries/business/DSC_0035.jpg" rel="lightbox[business]" title="Stylish button 2 suit with contrast buttonholes light weight high twist cool wool Holland &amp; Sherry from £695, choice of 90 designs/colours">Click for more information</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="suit-gallery">
  <img src="../images/galleries/business/DSC_0010_sm.jpg" alt="Classic button 2 business suit with an out ticket pocket. Grey wool Holland &amp; Sherry Perennial" width="164" height="247" />
  <div class="suit-gallery-btn">
    <a href="../images/galleries/business/DSC_0010.jpg" rel="lightbox[business]" title="Classic button 2 suit with an out ticket pocket. Grey wool Holland &amp; Sherry Perennial from £895, choice of 120 designs/colours" >Click for more information</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="suit-gallery">
  <img src="../images/galleries/business/DSC_0024_sm.jpg" alt="Modern 2 button business suit grey 100% Yorkshire worsted" width="164" height="247" />
  <div class="suit-gallery-btn">
    <a href="../images/galleries/business/DSC_0024.jpg" rel="lightbox[business]" title="Modern 2 button suit 100% Yorkshire worsted from £795 choice of 85 designs/colours" >Click for more information</a>
</div>
```

I am wanting to add a sharethis mail link to each instance of `.suit-gallery-btn`, however I have no idea how do this, I would also like to a title of link of link into the caption option, and also image URL into the image option, below is what I have currently,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    stWidget.addEntry({
    "service":"email",
    "element": document.getElementById('button_1'),
    "url":"http://sharethis.com",
    "title":"What do you think to this suit?",
    "type":"large",
    "text":"What do you think to this suit?" ,
    "image": "",
    "summary":""
    });
});
```

I also know that I will have to select the element based on a class and not the id, I need to do this for however many `.suit-gallery-btn` there are.

I am toally lost.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$(".suit-gallery-btn").each(function(){

    $(this).append("<span class='share-span'></span>"); // ShareThis button will be inserted in this span, which we are appending to each <div class="suit-gallery-btn">

    var suitLink = $(this).find('a'); // the "click more information" link. you will need the href and title from this element.

    stWidget.addEntry({
        "service":"email",
        "element": $(this).find('.share-span')[0],
        "url":suitLink.attr('href'),
        "title":suitLink.attr('title'),
        "type":"large",
        "text":suitLink.attr('title'),
        "image": suitLink.attr('href'),
        "summary":suitLink.attr('title')
    });


});
```

Here is a JS fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/RR26b/

(There are errors from invalid image references, and from lack of a ShareThis Publisher Key, but the concept should work)

Comment: Many thanks for this, how can I stop the sharethis widget just showing the same info for each button? If I trigger the widget on one of my links that data is then used for all the sharethis buttons